# How can I find out how often a program has started in Ubuntu?

Tags: java

How can I find how often a program (like firefox, teeworlds, thunderbird, etc.) has launched? I'm a Java programmer, so solutions that must be implemented programmatically are acceptable, and preferred.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It's not clear what your question has to do with Ubuntu. Also this question is programming related.

Comment: @UwePlonus it's not necessarily a programming question. If you ignore the extraneous first sentence in the OP it reads fine and is clear what they are after; a way to determine how many times a program has been launched in Ubuntu.

Comment: @amc but I don't see how this is related to Ubuntu. I don't think that there is a Ubuntu specific way that does not work in Debian or Red Hat...

Comment: @UwePlonus of course it's relevant! And so what if the solution also happens to work on Debian or others? Most "Ubuntu answers" work on Debian, it doesn't make them less relevant.

Comment: @UwePlonus In ubuntu is there any way to get the times that a program has started to work? I`m not asking about java; my question is about ubuntu.

Comment: I think this is a great question about **Ubuntu**. But Have you checked in logs or stuff like that to see if it's logged there? is something generated every time the program has started, like a log or such, then you can just count the logs. - Just an idea...

Comment: Perhaps someone knowledgeable about [Zeitgeist](http://zeitgeist-project.com/) could say if it can give this info? Btw, even from a programming standpoint, this sort of question tends to be OS-specific; techniques that work well in one GNU/Linux system might work poorly or not at all in another. (For example, if Zeitgeist will give this info, that would only help on OSes like Ubuntu where Zeitgeist is running in the default configuration, to have collected the information.) @UwePlonus Please keep in mind that "Development on Ubuntu" is [explicitly on-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: There's always the system log. See if you can get the kernel to log all `fork`s and `exec`s, then `grep` it for a string, remove internal `fork/exec`s by any programs, then calculate average differences.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I could come up with is to wrap the programs you're interested in. That of course is only feasible if the list of programs you want to observe is short enough.

Look after the command `dpkg-divert`. It lets you move files under package control aside while still being managed by the packaging system. Something like this could work:

```
# dpkg-divert --add --local --divert /usr/bin/firefox.mylogwrapped --rename /usr/bin/firefox
```

Then link a log script to the original path like

```
# ln -s /usr/local/bin/mylogwrapper /usr/bin/firefox
```

Inside that wrapper do whatever you need to do and then `exec /usr/bin/firefox.mylogwrapped "$@"`. You can access the name of the originally called binary with the `$0` environment variable.

Good luck!